# Laravel Voyager Charts not showing in the Dashboard

Tags: laravel, vuejs2

Hi Guys I'm using laravel Voyager in my Project after I added the **Google Analytics Client ID**

to The Admin Still not showing **Charts** in **Dashboard** ???

anyone can help me with this issue please

Answer (score 0):

At first I guess you should install an analytics tool on your page.
go to https://analytics.google.com/analytics and register your website. then copy the code like

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-***********"></script> <script> window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || []; function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);} gtag('js', new Date()); gtag('config', 'UA-***********'); </script>
```

and past it inside head tag as the first element. 
I think your answer is in here-
[Google Analytics on Laravel Voyager Admin](https://github.com/the-control-group/voyager/issues/2216)